# Keyboard shortcut to navigate to next/previous search match in eclipse for java

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to assign a shortcut to this function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you hover over the arrows to get to the next or previous result, eclipse shows you the shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>.

Comment: What about doing this without having to active the search result window first?

Comment: @ArneEvertsson, I posted [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20594579/527056) how to achieve this without having to activate the search result window first

Answer (score 27):

**`CTRL+K` forward and `CTRL+SHIFT+K` back** :

Highlight a word or phrase you want to search for. Hitting CTRL+K will take you to the next without having to open the Search control window. Please also upvote @feedbackloop for his comment here/below with the shortcut to go to the previous!

I'm using CFEclipse. I don't know if the same applies to what workbench you're using.

Comment: I was looking for the same: It's `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`k`.

Comment: Epic! better than `Ctrl+j` I have been using.

Answer (score 21):

The solution I use to go to next/previous search match even when the search result view is **not focused** is as follows:

- Use the prev/next shortcuts as usual when the search view is focused: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>.
- Configure the same keys to focus the search result view when it's not focused. Window > Preferences > General > Keys - Search: "Show View (Search)", Press "Copy Command", Set binding: "CTRL+.", when: "Editing Text" (and similar configuration for "CTRL+,").

That way these keyboard shortcuts will work both when search results are active and inactive.

**Note:** In order not to sacrifice the ability to use shortcut keys to navigate to previous/next results in other views (e.g. Problems view, etc) you can assign different keys for navigating the currently focused view.

Comment: Great solution. P.S.: After switching through search results, F12 focuses the editor again (setting "Activate Editor").

Comment: Needs double tap...fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I could find was to use AutoHotkey. Eg, when ctrl+alt+right is pressed, it focuses the search view (+!qs), does next (^.), then focuses the editor (^e).

```
#If WinActive("ahk_exe eclipse.exe") && WinActive("ahk_class SWT_Window0")
    ^!Right::Send +!qs^.^e
    ^!Left::Send +!qs^,^e
#If
```

Comment: This is great thank you. I used {enter} instead of ^e as enter opens editor and focuses result whereas eclipse neon popped up a menu with ^e.

Comment: Ah probably I customized my key bindings to use ^e (ctrl+e) to focus the editor.